Query regarding SQS polling behaviour of Spring Cloud AWS 3.0.X
Have a query around  the  below example scenario  from the docs
Example:
Let’s consider a scenario where the container is configured for: maxConcurrentMessages = 20, maxMessagesPerPoll = 10, maxDelayBetweenPolls = 5 seconds, and a pollTimeout = 10 seconds.
The container starts in low throughput mode, meaning it’ll attempt a single poll for 10 messages. If any messages are returned, it’ll switch to high throughput mode, and will make up to 2 simultaneous polls for 10 messages each. If all 20 messages are retrieved, it’ll not attempt any more polls until messages are processed. If after the 5 seconds for maxDelayBetweenPolls 6 messages have been processed, the framework will poll for the 6 messages. If the queue is depleted and a poll returns no messages, it’ll enter low throughput mode again and perform only one poll at a time.
Query:
In the above example,
i) What happens if all the 20 messages polled are processed within 1 second. Will we will wait for 5 seconds (which is the value for maxDelayBetweenPolls) , to poll for the next set of messages?
ii) What happens if 19 out of 20 messages polled were processed within 1 second . But 20th message took 3 seconds. Will it wait until the 20 message is processed and only then poll for the next set of messages?
If this is the case, is there any way to not wait for maxDelayBetweenPolls seconds and instead as soon as a  worker thread is available we poll for as many messages as the number of worker threads available.
